# Probability : expected value

Tags: probability

Homework help: 
Suppose that at a party there are n guests, and a place is assigned to each guest. But the guests do not know this and they occupy the seats randomly. What is the expected number of the pairs of guests that just have to swap their places

Any hints to where to start?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a sorting question in disguise. Think about the total number of pairs that can be generated from the set of guests, and then determine the probability that the pair  should be swapped.